# Run command line with date parameters with C# in SSIS (2015)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I need to run a command line on a Windows server with date parameters using C# in SSIS (2015)

The command line example:

D:\TEST >dotnet TEST.dll --fromDateTime "2018-11-21" --toDateTime "2018-11-22"

Can you assist me in the script?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack we are not a coding service please edit your question show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution

Comment: I think this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21) help you.

Comment: here see this link and then see how to add a variable [Link](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/executing-msdos-commands-in-ssis/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance.

I found the answer to my problem:

1. Can't use the SSIS Execute Process Task since it is applicable to EXE or BAT
2. Don't want / Can't change my DotNet DLL to an EXE since it is very limiting and the project includes many other factors that are not under this issue (and the dev is done by other teams)
3. here is the C# with the answer - it works! :)

   public void Main()
       {
           string FromDate = Dts.Variables["User::FromDate"].Value.ToString();
           string ToDate = Dts.Variables["User::ToDate"].Value.ToString();
           string TEST_Path = Dts.Variables["$Package::TEST_Path"].Value.ToString();
           string TEST_ExePath = Dts.Variables["$Package::TEST_ExePath"].Value.ToString();

   ```
       var strCmdText = @"c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe";


       var parameters = TEST_ExePath.ToString() + " --fromDateTime " + FromDate.ToString() + " --toDateTime " + ToDate.ToString();
       System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

       p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(strCmdText, parameters);
       p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = TEST_Path;

       p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

       bool fireAgain = false;

       try
       {
           p.Start();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", "Exception encountered: " + e.ToString(), String.Empty, 0);
       }


       p.WaitForExit();


       Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task Example", "Exit code = " + p.ExitCode.ToString(), String.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);


       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   }
   ```